# Java: Implementing hashCode() to ensure permutations of an int array always returns same hash

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to make my `hashCode()`-implementation return the same hashCode for all permutations of an int-array.

Requirements:

- If array A is a permutation of B then A.equals(B) must yield true
- Two arrays who are a permutation of one another must return the same hashCode.

I have already written the functions to provide me with all the permutations (rotations and reflections) of the arrays, but I don't really understand how I can make them all return the same code, since there are no object properties to base the code upon.

What I've tried so far is gathering the `Arrays.hashCode()` of all the permutations, summing them up into a `long`, dividing them by the number of permutations and returning the result as an int.

While this doesn't feel like a good solution (using the median is quite vague, thus might result in collisions), it's not working anyway. I've found objects that are not among the valid permutations to return the same hashCode.

**Example 1: Reflection**
These two are equal because arr2 is a reflection of arr1.

```
int[] arr1 = {0,2,4,1,3}     int[] arr2 = {4,2,0,3,1}   
[X 0 0 0 0]                  [0 0 0 0 X]
[0 0 X 0 0]                  [0 0 X 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 X]                  [X 0 0 0 0]
[0 X 0 0 0]                  [0 0 0 X 0]
[0 0 0 X 0]                  [0 X 0 0 0]
```

**Example 2: Rotation**
These two are permutations of each other because arr2 is a rotated arr1.

```
int[] arr1 = {0,2,4,1,3}     int[] arr2 = {4,1,3,0,2}   
[X 0 0 0 0]                  [0 0 0 0 X]
[0 0 X 0 0]                  [0 X 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 X]                  [0 0 0 X 0]
[0 X 0 0 0]                  [X 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 X 0]                  [0 0 X 0 0]
```

**Q:** How can I implement a `hashCode()`-function to return the same hash for every array-object that is a permutation of one another, one that would return the same hashCode for all of the above examples?

**Update:**
The reason I cannot sort and compare the arrays is that all arrays that will ever be compared will all contain the values 0..n-1. The reason for this is that the index represents the chessboard row, while the value represents the column at which the queen is placed. (See [n queens puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) if you're interested).
Hence, I am unable to calculate the hashcode by sorting first. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply sort the array, and then use `Arrays.hashCode()` to compute the hashCode.

Your collection looks like a Bag, or MultiSet. Several libraries have implementations for such a data structure. [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) for example.

Comment: I cannot use this approach, since all valid and invalid arrays will contain the same values (0..n-1).

Comment: So what? The contract of hashCode() is that two equal objects must have the same hashCode. Not that unequal objects must have different hashCodes. That would be impossible, since there is an infinity of possible objects, and only 2^32 integer values.

Comment: A sorted valid permutation would look the same as a sorted invalid permutation, thus would the invalid permutation return the same hashcode as the valid one. What am I not getting?

Comment: @krystah It is called the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: Ah, I get it now. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do it would be to sum all the values in the array and then use a bit mixer to spread the bits in the result. The sum of all the values will be the same regardless of the order, so you're guaranteed that any permutation of the array will result in the same value.

For example:

```
int hash = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
{
    hash += array[i];
}

// See link below for reference
hash ^= (hash >>> 20) ^ (hash >>> 12);
return h ^ (hash >>> 7) ^ (hash >>> 4);
```

I got the bit mixer code from http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/integer.html. That page is full of good information that you probably want to know.

You might also consider working in the array length if it's different among the arrays you'll be comparing. You could also multiply the result by the highest (or lowest) value in the array, etc. Anything that would help you differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that wraps your array.

The `hashCode` method needs to perform an operation that is commutative, so that different permutations have the same hash code.  Compute a hash code that is the sum of the elements in the array.  The sum will not change if the order changes.

You should override `equals` also.

Comment: This is currently what I've done, but the sum of the hashCodes is too big for a int, so I had to sum it up into a `long`, then divide it by the amount of permutation, thus returning the median. This is not working as of now, as arrays who are not permutations can also return the same hash

Comment: @krystah: you won't be able to find any method which guarantees a unique hashCode. There is an infinite number of arrays, and only 2^32 possible hashCodes.

Comment: +1, a commutative, associative operator is the best general answer (xor is typical). Due to the specific data set (using just low values), you may want to xor each `1 << (x%32)` instead of just each x. This happens to be optimal for 5*5 values.

Comment: Hash collisions are possible, but that's okay.  As long as two permutations of the same elements return the same hash code, then it's okay if two arrays of different elements return the same hash code.  That's one reason why you should also override `equals`.  Also, I don't think it matters if the hash code sum overflows an `int`.

Comment: Less efficient, but you could return the hashcode for the sorted array.

Comment: Actually more efficiently return the hashcode of a hash set containing all the elements in the array.

Comment: It is totally okay if the sum of the hashCodes is too big for an int.  _Let it overflow._  The sum of the hashCodes mod 2^32 is still a good hash.

Comment: I understand how there might be collisions since there is a limited amount of hashCodes, but how on earth am I going to be able to compare these arrays if not by hashcodes?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the arrays before you calculate the hash or compare them within equals.

Comment: You're going to sort an array to compute its hash code? I hope it's a small array!

Comment: @JimMischel sorting is needed for equals as well, so this has to be spent anyhow. I would store the arrays in canonical (sorted) form. This should not be a problem, since all these objects are equal. The effort for sorting is then only spent when the array changes.

Comment: Sorting is not required for equality testing. You can create a hash map from one of the arrays and look up each item from the other. That is O(n) whereas sorting is O(n log n).

Comment: @JimMischel True, but since we are talking about an array of ints the object allocations happening when crating the hash table will be slower for most practically sized problems. Of course unless we run our own int hash table implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it sounds like you're doing a brute-force solution to the N-queens problem, whereby you generate every possible position of the queens on the board, eliminate reflections/rotations so you're left with all unique board layouts, and then search for acceptable layouts. As mentioned in the other answers, you cannot rely on `hashCode` alone for duplicate elimination, because even a well-written hash function has the possibility of collisions.

Instead, I'd suggest defining a canonical layout for a given equivalence set of rotations/reflections. One likely approach would be to define a sort ordering for your layouts, doing a pairwise comparison of elements, until you find an unequal position. The canonical representation for a given layout would be the layout with the lowest ordering.

Then, as you generate your layouts, the first thing you do is get the canonical representation of that layout, and only proceed if you've not yet seen the canonical version. For instance:

```
 public class Chessboard implements Comparable<Chessboard> {

    private int[] rows;

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
      return other != null && 
             other instanceof Chessboard && 
             Arrays.equals(rows, other.rows);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
       return Arrays.hashCode(rows);
    }

    public int compareTo(Chessboard other) {
       if (rows.length != other.rows.length) {
          return rows.length - other.rows.length;
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          int c = rows[i] - other.rows[i];
          if (c != 0) return c;
       }
       return 0;
    }

    public List<Chessboard> getPermutations() {
       /* Your permutations code here. */
    }

    public Chessboard getCanonicalLayout() {
       List<Chessboard> permutations = getPermutations();
       Collections.sort(permutations);
       return permutations.get(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Set<Chessboard> checked = new HashSet<Chessboard>();
       for (Chessboard b : getAllLayouts()) {
          Chessboard c = b.getCanonicalLayout();
          if (checked.contains(c)) {
             continue;
          }
          checked.add(c);
          if (isSolution(c)) {
             System.out.println("Found a solution: " + c);
          }
       }
    }
 }
```